# Getting textview id from database and using it

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm working on a android project.In my sqlite database i got some questions , answers and textview id's which is connected to these questions.In my xml i have "textA","textB","textBLABLA".Also i have these id's in my database as well.

To get textview id's from database i use this sql code.

```
private void getText(int id) {
Cursor getTextView = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT textView FROM questions WHERE id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
int textIndex = getTextView.getColumnIndex("textView");
```

I can get the value.But how can i use this value to edit that textview ? For example changing its background color like ;

```
questionTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: can you show the code of how you put these id in database?

Comment: I put them manually via DB Browser for SQLite.Then used android device manager to change it with old one.I can get the values but dont know how can i use them as mentioned

Comment: Create a textview object with this id (from your db) 

`TextView questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(idFetchedFromDb);`
and then use this object to edit text view.

Comment: int textIndex = getTextView.getColumnIndex("textView");
getTextView.moveToFirst();
// You forgot this //
`int textViewId = getTextView.getInt(textIndex);`
TextView questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(`textViewId`);

Comment: Didnt work :/ My app crashes.Actually i tried changing background color with this ; 
questionTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
Then it crashes

Comment: do make sure you call questionTextView.setBackground(Color.Black) after you initialized the textview object from DB.

Comment: Code is at last line.Changing text crashes app too.
questionTextView.setText("Testing");

Comment: I'm getting null pointer error. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

you just fetched the column index not the value from the column.

```
private void getText(int id) {
Cursor getTextView = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT textView FROM questions WHERE id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
int textIndex = getTextView.getColumnIndex("editText"); // this gives you the column index you requested

// AD THIS AFTER ABOVE CODE
if(getTextView.moveToNext()){
    int textViewId = getTextView.getInt(textIndex); // this gives you the value from the column index you provide and and the row you on which the current cursor is
    TextView questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId); 
    /* UPDATE */
    questionTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
}
```

you need to fetch the value from the fetched column index.

Comment: I did this.Now i want to change background color of that textview with 
questionTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
But it crashes.What could be the problem ?

Comment: Yes. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Then probably its ID mismatch.

Comment: They do match.I have textA value on my database.And its id is textA on xml code.

Comment: the id is generated in R class as an integer which is used to identify the resource uniquely. if you are saving textA in your SQL DB then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: the id generated and saved in R class is like this 

0x7f1100dc;

Comment: Yeap thats what it was.I thought i could get the "ID" which i wrote "textA".I'm getting unique numbers.Is there a way to get "textA" ?

Comment: Or should i change values at database to those unique numbers ?

Comment: getting textA wont help. you need the unique integer to find the resource and bind it to respectively.

Comment: change the values in the database to those unique numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to see those unique numbers without using Log ?

Comment: in your imports right click on R and select goto>declaration and then in R class use search feature to find what you wish.